# Insert unnumbered headings in toc automatically

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, starred-version

When I use a numbered heading like `\section` or `\chapter`, the heading is automatically added to the table of contents. If I use an unnumbered heading like `\section*` or `\chapter*`, I have to add another line

```
\section*{Criteria}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Criteria}
```

It's quite annoying. Is there a way that I can have this happen automatically? I've tried

```
\renewcommand{section}[1]{\section*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
```

But that fails to compile.

I was able to use

```
\newcommand{mysection}[1]{\section*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
```

But this seems fairly clunky as well, and it requires changing all of my sectioning commands in the document.

Comment: the ams agrees with you, and `amsbook` does add starred headings to the toc automatically.  but then there are questions about how to get rid of them.  maybe the solution is to provide the feature, but give an option to suppress it.  (sometimes one just can't win.)

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) it is straight-forward to condition between starred versions and optional arguments. As such, the following redefinition of `\section` automatically inserts the appropriate starred version in the ToC:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \section*
      \oldsection*{#3}% Insert \section*{...}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#3}% Add ToC entry
    }{% \section
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{...}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[..]{...}
    }%
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\section[Second section]{Another section}

\section*{Next section}

\section*[Final section]{Last section}

\end{document}
```

Note though that `\tableofcontents` also uses `\section*` in `article`. As such, it will be included in the ToC necessarily under this condition. A minor redefinition of `\tableofcontents` would fix this though.

Also note that I've left the optional argument out of the processing when the user inputs `\section*[..]{...}`, as this is typically not used. However, one can add that condition if needed.

Comment: You could also add the mark-mechanism, so that headers get updated as well.